# Why does this substitution failure create an error, again?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

I asked a question just before about why `std::enable_if<false>` cannot be used in SFINAE contexts, as in:

```
template <typename T, typename DEFAULTVOID = void>
struct TemplatedStruct {};

template <typename T>
struct TemplatedStruct<T, std::enable_if_t<false>> {}; // enable_if expression
// isn't dependent on template type, is always false and so is an error
```

However in the following example it is dependent on a template argument, but this also creates an error:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename value_t_arg>
struct underlyingtype 
{
    static inline constexpr bool bIsIntegralType = 
        std::is_integral_v<value_t_arg>;

    template <typename T, typename DEFAULTVOID = void>
    struct IsSpecialType {
        static inline constexpr bool bIsSpecialType = false;
    };
    
    template <typename T>
    struct IsSpecialType<T, std::enable_if_t<bIsIntegralType>> {
        static inline constexpr bool bIsSpecialType = true;
    };
    
    // This also creates an error, this is essentially the same as above
    template <typename T>
    struct IsSpecialType<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<value_t_arg>>> {
        static inline constexpr bool bIsSpecialType = true;
    };


};

int main()
{
    underlyingtype<int> g1; // Works
    underlyingtype<double> g2; // std::enable_if_t<false, void>:
                               // Failed to specialize alias template
}
```

In the first case of using `std::enable_if_t<false>` it fails to compile no matter what I instantiate. However in this other case `underlyingtype<int> g1;` works while when I instantiate it with a double it then fails to compile, which makes me think they're two different problems.

Edit: I should mention, this fails to compile with Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.3.

Comment: In general, please, try to make the code more readable, even if that just requires some strategic newline here an there.

Comment: SFINAE should work on substitution, but there is no substitution here.

Comment: @Evg std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<value_t_arg>>> Is a substitution, isn't it? value_t_arg is a template type parameter

Comment: Please show the exact source you have compiled (no duplicate declarations) and the exact error messages you are getting.

Comment: Not really. In that template, `value_t_arg` is just an external fixed argument, not the one a compiler is trying to deduce.

Comment: @Enlico I asked that question also, the answer seemed to be that std::enable_if_t<false> always evaluates to an error, because false isn't based on a dependent type, it's an error in itself. However in the above code it seems to be based on a dependent type, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_t<value_t_arg>> , 'value_t_arg' is a template parameter type

Comment: Where is the specific error message you get?

Comment: @Useless std::enable_if_t<false, void>: Failed to specialize alias template, at the line where I try to do std::enable_if_t<std::_is_integral_t<value_t_arg>> . I thought value_t_arg was a dependent type and so anything based on it could fail in a SFINAE context, but the thing is it's not a dependent type in the context of the inner template. When the compiler looks at the inner template the outer template has already been instantiated, and value_t_arg template parameter is already known, and so std::enable_if_t is given a constant or a known type.

Comment: @Zebrafish, the comment comes up as consequence of me flagging the question as duplicate. I wasn't really asking a question. I see the difference between the two questions, but that difference is illusory, so I think it's still good for other readers to mark this question as duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `// Failed to specialize alias template`

For one, there's no alias template in your code.¹ You're just delcaring `bIsIntegralType` to be exactly the same thing as `std::is_integral_v<value_t_arg>`, which is fixed (to `false` or `true`) as soon as the instantiation of `underlyingtype` takes place.

Therefore, the two specializations

```cpp
    template <typename T>
    struct IsSpecialType<T, std::enable_if_t<bIsIntegralType>> {
        static inline constexpr bool bIsSpecialType = true;
    };

    // This also creates an error, this is essentially the same as above
    template <typename T>
    struct IsSpecialType<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<value_t_arg>>> {
        static inline constexpr bool bIsSpecialType = true;
    };
```

are the same thing, hence clang says

```
Class template partial specialization 'IsSpecialType<T>' cannot be redeclared
```

And this is independent of what `value_t_arg` you pass to `underlyingtype`.

When removing either of the two identical specializations, the code is ok as regards `underlyingtype<int> g1;`, but it is still invalid upon trying to instantiate `underlyingtype<double>`, because `value_t_arg` is "blocked" to `double` in that case, which makes `bIsIntegralType` be just a `false` compile-time value, which in turns means that you're passing an always-and-ever-`false` to `std::enable_if_v`.

Putting it in another way, when you ask for `underlyingtype<double>`, the compiler starts instantiating the class `underlyingtype` with `value_t_arg = double`; at this point the compiler hasn't even looked at `IsSpecialType`, but it knows that `bIsIntegralType == false`, which makes the code for `IsSpecialType`'s specialization invalid as per the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67647013/why-does-this-substitution-failure-create-an-error).

---

(¹) An [alias template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) is a templated type alias,

```cpp
template <typename T>
using new_name = old_name<T>;
```

whereas in your code there's no `using` at all, so there couldn't be a type alias, let alone an alias template.

---

Based on this and the previous question, it looks like you're trying to get into SFINAE and Template Meta-Programming. If I may give you a suggestion, a good way to learn it is to read and understand how the [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) library works. There's ***a lot*** of TMP and SFINAE there, but the quality of the code is high (imho) and the code itself is extremely well documented and, hence, understandable (obviously it takes time).

Comment: But... <value_t_arg> is a dependent type, so std::enable_if<std::is_integral_v<value_t_arg>> should not always evaluate to the same thing, right? It's dependent on the type passed in.

Comment: No, I'll explain better. Gimme a moment.

Comment: Do you mean to say because value_t_arg isn't a type within that template it doesn't count as a dependent type within the context of THAT template? But it's a dependent type only of the outer template? So once the inner template is instantiated value_t_arg isn't a dependent type anymore?

Comment: @Zebrafish, when the compiler looks at the specialization, `bIsIntegralType` is just a plain `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line:

```
std::cout << underlyingtype<double>::IsSpecialType<char>::bIsSpecialType << "\n";
```

How should we go about interpreting it?

- `underlyingtype` is a template.
- `underlyingtype<double>` is not a template, it is a type, a specific instantiation of `underlyingtype`.
- `underlyingtype<double>::IsSpecialType` is a template, a member of a (non-template) class type `underlyingtype<double>`  This template has a single parameter T.
- `underlyingtype<double>::IsSpecialType<char>` is an instantiation of the preceding template.

Now, when instantiating a template, *its* parameters are substituted with actual arguments. Failure to perform such substitution is not an error. In case of `underlyingtype<double>::IsSpecialType`, the parameter is `T`. However `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<value_t_arg>>>` does not depend on `T`, so no substitution takes place.